# Way to implement Random Forest on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying to find a way to use a random forest classification on an Android app (developed under Android Studio). I looked for TensorFlow Lite but TensorFlow does not implement the Random Forest model yet, it has been deleted from the community repo to be added to the next version of TF.

Can you help me figuring a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Smile (Statistical Machine Intelligence and Learning Engine)](https://github.com/haifengl/smile)

Comment: Thank you for your help